# What is the output when building android framework from the source tree

Tags: java, android, android-source, dalvik, android-sdk-tools

I am planning to modify the Android framework within the source tree. I have few questions,

1. If i build only the framework directory what will be the output? Will it be a jar file or the whole system image?
2. How can I use the built framework to develop apps that use this custom framework? (will there be any android.jar or something similar?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you planning on flashing your custom framework to a device? Just building the framework.jar won't get you very far, since your app will only run on devices using your custom framework.

Comment: Yes planning to flash the full rom. But I want to know how can I also change the sdk. Is it from the same build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Building only the framework (`mmm frameworks/base`) is not enough. If you do in this way you will only obtain a bunch of jar files containing built framework. To use the modifications, you need to build the full image against which you will test your changes. Do not forget to do `make update-api`
2. To use the modified framework, you need to build sdk. To do this, you need to do the following steps after you've updated the api (see more https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/master/docs/howto_build_SDK.txt):

   ```
   source build/evnsetup.sh
   lunch sdk-eng
   make sdk
   ```

   After you've built the SDK, you need to point Android Studio project to the new location of the SDK. To do this, create a new project in Android Studio, select the root folder in the Project panel, and make a right click on it selecting the "Open Module Settings" item (or simply pressing F4). Point the location of the SDK to the folder with newly created SDK (it should be somewhere under the `out/host/linux-x86/` directory if you use Linux-based host operating system).

Comment: So if I modify the framework, the sdk files are automatically changed right? Or they have a different source other then the framework directory?

Comment: I have seen that the sdk sources are different. So, to keep things in sync I need to edit same files twice? e.g. one from the sdk and one from the framework?

Comment: In short if I want to add some functionality to some exisiting classes in the framework, will I need to update both the framework src and the sdk source I am using? Or compiling the framework is enough, e.g. it will also produce an sdk.

Comment: I think you mess now SDK and API. SDK is a set of tools (that also contains an API) to develop Android applications. Usually, there is no need to make modifications to these tools. At the same time, when you make modifications to the API you need to run update-api (but there is no need to do any modifications to the SDK tools).